# "Error: Couldn't find a table" when installing Rtools

Tags: r, rtools

I am trying to install Rtools using the following code:

```r
install.Rtools(choose_version = TRUE, 
               check = FALSE, 
               GUI = TRUE, 
               page_with_download_url = "https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/")
```

However, it then gives me the following error message:

> "Error: Couldn't find table."

I have no real idea what this error message means or how to fix it, so any help would be welcome!

Comment: Seems to be reported here: https://github.com/talgalili/installr/issues/148. It would probably be easier just to install RTools outside of R yourself.

Comment: The instructions at the url (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools) appear to be clear-enough to do it manually, I agree with @MrFlick. (And since that issue's associated PR ([installr#156](https://github.com/talgalili/installr/pull/156)) appears to have lost momentum, it might be a while?)